# remote syslog-ng

Tags: syslog, vmware-workstation, remote-login

I have two Ubuntu's in VMware Workstation, one of them is Ubuntu 14 (client) and the other one is Ubuntu 15 mate (server) and they are pinged together.
I've installed syslog-ng on both sides and I want to send client side syslog-ng logs to the server side syslog-ng remotely. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For quickstart, see:https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configure-clients.html

and https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configure-servers.html

Also, don't forget to adjust your firewall settings on the port you are using.

Comment: thnx but it didn't help

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is?